# Get Identifier of CMS page/block

Tags: blocks, magento-1, cms

I would like to find CMS block identifier in Magento backend. The only thing I have is URL. I found many solutions here on SE. But my technical knowledge (or lack of it) does not allow me to perform the operation.

The code I found:

```
$PageData = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->load($_product->getUrlKey(),'identifier');
echo print_r($BuyingTitle->getData());
exit;
```

or this:

```
$current_id = Mage::getBlockSingleton('cms/page')->getPage()->getId();
```

Where should I put this code? `.phtml` file? How do I run it?

Edit:

I have a website `www.mymagento.com/example/about-us`, which was made by an outsource company and where I can't find all the ends. I have access to magento back-end.
When I go `CMS -> Pages -> Manage content`, I can't find the `/about-us` page. So I'm trying to retrieve the Identifier of the page with php request, but I'm not very familiar with it.

Comment: The code you posted is not relevant to your problem. To guide you step by step, it would be helpful to know what you are trying to achieve. Where do you get the URL from? What do you want to do with the identifier? As it stands the question is not really answerable (although I gave it a try, hope it helps)

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to get identifier of page

```
$cmsPageUrlKey = Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier();
```

instead of

```
$current_id = Mage::getBlockSingleton(‘cms/page’)->getPage()->getId();
```

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to find CMS-block identifier in Magento backend. The only
>   thing I have is URL

I'm going to assume you mean CMS **page**, otherwise it is not possible. CMS **blocks** can be rendered dynamically in many places and are not directly related to a URL.

But both snippets you show do **not** give you a CMS page based on a URL. The first one tries to find a CMS page with an identifier that's equal to a given product URL which makes no sense under normal circumstances. And the second one might give you the numeric ID of the **current** page.

If you have a URL `$url` in the form `http://www.example.com/my-page` and it is the URL of a CMS page, `my-page` is the identifier. So you could just strip of the base URL `http://example.com/`:

```
$baseUrlLen = strlen(Mage::getBaseUrl());
$identifier = substr($url, 0, $baseUrlLen);
```

Where to put it depends on where you want to use it and what you want to do with it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I realize my formulation is unclear. 
So I have a page 'http://example.com/my-page'. I would like to find "my-page" in Magento back-end. And preferably all static-blocks used in this page also.
I found this solution to create a '.php') file, put in the root of the website and run it from browser, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: The problem with static blocks is, without actually calling the URL it is not possible to find out which static blocks are used, there are too many factors. What you could do is logging used static blocks to a file - but I still don't know what you actually need (and more important: why) so I don't know if that's suitable for you. Please update the question with more details.